# Formulário de contato PHPMailer não funciona

Tags: php, html, ajax, phpmailer

Estou usando a classe PHPMailer para enviar e-mails, só que toda vez que clico no botão de enviar ele fica com a mensagem eternamente no "Enviando sua mensagem...". Não sei se o problema está no AJAX ou no meu `mail.php`.

No console da o seguinte erro:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at m.parseJSON (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
    at Pc (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
    at x (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
```

Segue abaixo meu código:

```
<form role="form" class="Main__Form--contact" method="post" action="mail.php">
                <div class="Input__groups">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Insira seu nome" required>
                </div>
                <div class="Input__groups">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Insira seu e-mail" required>
                </div>
                <div class="Input__groups">
                    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Insira o assunto" required>
                </div>
                <div class="Input__groups">
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5" placeholder="Escreva sua mensagem" required></textarea>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="Button--blue Button_submit">Enviar</button>
            </form>
```

AJAX que estou utilizando:

```
var form = $('.Main__Form--contact');
     form.submit(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var form_status = $('<div class="Main__Form--status"></div>');

     var data = {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        subject: $('#subject').val(),
         message: $('#message').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {'data': data},
        beforeSend: function(){
            form.prepend( form_status.html('<p class="text---white Column---left"><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Enviando sua mensagem...</p>').fadeIn() );
        },
        success: function (d) {
        d = JSON.parse(d);
        if(d == 1){
                form_status.html('<p class="Column---left" style="color: #00ff00">Mensagem enviada com sucesso!</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
                $('#name').val("");
                $('#email').val("");
                $('#subject').val("");
                $('#message').val("");
            } else{
                form_status.html('<p class="Column---left" style="color: #ff0000">Ocorreu um erro ao tentar enviar a mensagem, tente novamente!</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error); 
        }
    });
});
```

Meu arquivo PHP mail.php:

```
<?php
   include_once "../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php";
   include_once "../PHPMailer/class.smtp.php";

   $data       = $_POST['data'];
   $name       = $data['name'];
   $subject    = $data['subject'];
   $message    = $data['message'];
   $email      = $data['email'];

   $mail = new PHPMailer(); 

   $mail->isSMTP();
   $mail->isHTML(true);
   $mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
   //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
   $mail->SingleTo = true;

   //configuração do email
   $mail->Port = '587'; 
   $mail->Host = 'xxxxx';
   $mail->Username = 'xxxx@xxxx.com.br'; 
   $mail->Password = 'xxxxxx';
   $mail->From     = 'xxx@xxx.com.br';
   $mail->FromName = 'Atendimento';

   $destinatario = 'xxxx@xxxx.com';
   $mail->addAddress($destinatario);
   $mail->addReplyTo($email);

   $mail->Subject = $subject;

   $remetente = '-=-=-=- Formulário de Contato -=-=-=-';
   $remetente = $remetente . '<br> Enviado por: '. $name;
   $remetente = $remetente . '<br> E-mail: '. $email;

   $documento = $message. ' <br><br><br><br>' . $remetente;
   $mail->Body = $documento;

   if (!$mail->send()) {
       //echo 'Erro:' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       echo json_encode(0);
       exit;
   }
   else {
    echo json_encode(1);
    exit;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está retornando do PHP dois possíveis valores:

`echo json_encode(0);` e `echo json_encode(1);`

O que é estranho pois isso não é JSON.

Você quer simplesmente ver se a variável retornada em `d` é `0` ou `1`, não precisa nem especificar o `dataType` no Ajax e no PHP alterar os `echo` para `echo 1;` e `echo 0;` e exclua a linha `d = JSON.parse(d);`.

#### Edit

Troque o:

```
var data = {
    name: $('#name').val(),
    email: $('#email').val(),
    subject: $('#subject').val(),
     message: $('#message').val()
};
```

Por:

```
var data = form.serialize();
```

Que irá enviar todos os campos do formulário. E em `data:` troque:

```
data: {'data': data},
```

Por:

```
data: data,
```

Comment: Não resolveu amigo

Comment: @darknone depois das alterações, o que retorna no Ajax?

Comment: O seguinte erro:

VM94:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success ((index):522)
    at j (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
    at x (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:4)

  Index linha 522:
 d = JSON.parse(d);

Comment: @darknone Apague a linha `d = JSON.parse(d);`

Comment: Agora ele mostra "Ocorreu um erro ao tentar enviar a mensagem!" e nenhum erro no console aparentemente

Comment: @darknone Então o código está correto, está retornando `0`. Tem que verificar no PHP o que está fazendo pra cair no 0.

Comment: @darknone Acho que o problema pode estar no `data`

Comment: @darknone Esse data tá esquisito. Perai que vou tentar reproduzir aqui...

Comment: O erro parece estar na classe do PHPMailer, ele retorna o erro no Network dizendo que ele não foi encontrado no diretório especificado ou é inválido.

Comment: Quanto a esse erro consegui resolver, agora o que está dando é: Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in C:\wamp64\www\class\phpMailer\class.smtp.php on line <i>344</i>

Comment: Cada hora que soluciono um erro, aparece outro.

Agora ta dando 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @darknone Veja o Edit que coloquei na pergunta. Isso facilita o envio do formulário. Se houver ainda erro vindo do PHP, o problema é no PHP.

Comment: Ele retorna esse erro no localhost, mas quando testo em domínio ele simplesmente da Internal server error no console e não retorna nenhum erro no PHP em network.

Answer (score 0):

De uma pesquisada em como achar o "error_log" do seu server PHP, para que consiga pegar mais detalhes do erro que esta acontecendo.

Comment: Olá, agradeço pela resposta amigo.

Já consegui arrumar o erro.